# Cannot change hdfs datanode directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, high-availability

The problem is that I can't change datanode directory for hdfs blocks.
If I put this property into hdfs-site.xml I cannot run datanode:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///var/hadoop/datanode</value>
</property>
```

jps command doesn't show that datanode is running. 
Also I tried to use these values but without success:

```
file:///var/hadoop/datanode
/var/hadoop/datanode
/var/hadoop/datanode/
```

I have all permitions for this folder:

```
chmod 777 -R /var/hadoop/datanode
```

When I remove dfs.datanode.data.dir property from configuration file and run:

```
hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```

it starts. But I do not know where hadoop stores its blocks.
Please, help me to set a correct data directory for the hdfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why. But when I changed permissions on the datanode it started work.

```
chown -R hadoop:hadoop /var/hadoop/datanode
```